# Formatting Json Data in C#

Tags: json

I have this Json Data in javascript, I want to use exact same data in C# how I can format this Data in C#.

```
  let header = '[{"data": [{"id": "Id","name": "Full Name","age": "Age"}]}]';
```

This is my controller in MVC:

```
      public ActionResult Index()
    {
        User user = new User();



        user.GridHeader = "[{data: [{id: Id,name: Full Name,age: Age}]}]";
        user.GridData = "[{data: [{id: 1,name: Sam,age: 32}, {id: 2,name: tom,age: 22}, {id: 3,name: mina,age: 25}]}]";

        return View(user);
    }
```

I need GridHeader  same format as header

Comment: create a model and bind it... what frameworks are you using MVC, WebAPI, Winforms???

Comment: @ johnny it is using MVC, I have added more explanation to my question.

Comment: your "header" variable is a string, not a JSON/Javascript object. It just happens to look like JSON. Is that what you want?

Comment: @ADyson It need to be json Data .

Comment: then lose the single quotes (in the javascript version). If you want to inject, say, user.GridHeader into your script, you could just do `var gridHeader = @user.GridHeader;` in the View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a model to bind to

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public UserData[] Data {get; set;}
}

public class UserData
{
     public int Id { get; set}
     public string Name { get; set;}
     public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

You should probably make the header static in the grid so you don't have to send it each time but if you don't just send it as the first record.

```
public ActionResult Index(UserDTO user)
{
    // your user data is in user.Data
    return View(user);
}
```

You should look up how the model binder works.  Here is an okay [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)